# How do I split the log file from rsyslog per Heroku application?

Tags: heroku, rsyslog

I followed the guide described here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#creating-your-own-syslog-drain to create my own rsyslog drain.

I configured my rsyslog with the following line:

```
:inputname, isequal, "imtcp" /var/log/heroku.log
```

That only worked after I updated my rsyslog from 5.x to 7.x. [A bug was preventing rsyslog to use the port 514](http://kb.monitorware.com/kbeventdb-detail-id-6922.html). But after the update it worked fine.

But now I want to split the logs one file per application. I found another question about that saying that I should use:

```
if $hostname isqual "d.123..." then /var/log/my_application.log
```

Where "d.123..." is the actual drain ID that Heroku provides. But that didn't work. I tried several variations following the [docs on rsyslog site](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_filter.html). None worked.

Again, using one single file worked. Every app on Heroku I configured to use that drain has successfully sent its log to it. But it seems that I can't find out how to split files one per application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUST found out that you have to manually create the log files. rsyslog can't create them and doesn't complain in its own log.

So, I used the configuration proposed in the article and ran `touch my-application-123.log` plus `chown syslog:adm my-application-123.log` then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I used this in my rsyslog drain:

```
if $syslogtag startswith 'app[postgres]' then /myapp/postgres
& ~
if $syslogtag startswith 'app[pgbackups]' then /myapp/postgres
& ~
if $syslogtag startswith 'heroku[' then /myapp/heroku
& ~
if $syslogtag startswith 'app[' then /myapp/app
& ~
```

HTH.

Comment: I'll give a try just to see if it works. But what I want is a bit different. You categorized by service (postgre, pgbackup, dynos, etc.) I want to categorize by application. There are multiple applications using the same drain and I want one log file per application.

Comment: Use the src hostname to distinguish. The host name will be d.<your-app-guid>

Comment: You can read above that I tried that - although I may have done that wrong. When searching for rsyslog+heroku this is what the first answer  says. No luck so far. :(